# Comparison is not allowed for operands of type 'float' and 'record'

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

[Screenshot problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK73e.png%60)

---

I'm trying to query certain input values from my EventHub with reference data that I retrieve from an SQL database. Is there a way to compare these 2 values? I have already tried parsing from record to float and vice versa, but this is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Comparison is not allowed for operands of type 'float' and 'record'....

There is a similar case to yours:[Error when trying to filter input in stream job query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42087326/error-when-trying-to-filter-input-in-stream-job-query), it is caused the mismatching of values in your expression. Float type can't be compared with Record type.

Please try to use [CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/cast-azure-stream-analytics?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstream-analytics%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json) built-in feature to convert the [Record into Float](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/data-types-azure-stream-analytics#type-mappings-and-serialization-formats).